# Why do I keep getting timeouts on my Rails/Heroku app on a dyno that doesn't sleep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, newrelic, mysql2

I recently deployed a rails app to Heroku and started getting timeouts at random times. I am currently using a professional dyno so it shouldn't be sleeping. It mainly happens after a period of inactivity and then the first request is hung up and timed out. After the first one, it does fine. I also am using New Relic to monitor the app. When it monitors the availability on any duration, it fails constantly. Even though I can pull the web app up on a browser fine. The errors it does catch say the issue is in the controller action that is rendering the page. But any action in any controller can cause this, as long as it's the first one called after a period of inactivity. I dropped some tracers in the code to pinpoint where the issue is. It seems the first bit of code that calls anything SQL related hangs up. New relic says that the code takes over 950,000+mS to complete. Depending on parameters and the session cookie, it may launch an SQL query at a different points in the action. The first line to launch a query is where New Relic says the issue is. I am using the Mysql2 gem and ClearDB for my database. The timeout issues aren't seen in development, possibly because of the 30 second timeout in Heroku.

Edit(2/7/18):
After removing code that New Relic said was hanging up, I'm left with no code that does anything SQL related for the homepage and controller action. I stopped using New Relics pings to determine up-time. I instead am using Up-time Robot to check the site. It confirmed my suspicions that new relics monitoring was wrong. So , without any SQL queries, it is working. I'm thinking of switching to PostgreSQL. Heroku says they are getting ClearDB to help. I'm waiting on them before I try anything else.

Edit(2/8/18): I switched to PostgreSQL. All the issues I was having are gone. I still can't explain why MySQL was causing timeouts though.

Comment: wanting dyno doesn't sleep is only one way, upgrading to premium account.

Comment: My understanding was that only free tier dynos would sleep. Hobby , professional, and perfermance dynos don't sleep. Plus, I would think heroku support would have said something about that in my service ticket. They believe it's in a single or group of controller actions and the timouts are from timeouts stacking. They recommended rack-timout. That didn't help much because the first request is the one that hangs. Subsequent requests work fine.

Comment: Here's the Heroku page on dynos. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos